# Handle Special characters like ° (degree)

Tags: data-loader, character-encoding

We are trying to import data with name "6400L -37° JIC SAE Flare Male x SAE O-Ring Boss ORB Male Adapter Long" but on inserting data we got value in sfdc as � (Special char).

We have enabled UTF-8 for data loader, let us know if is there anything we will need to take care too.

Comment: Does your input file has proper encoding? (UTF-8)

Comment: Some versions of Microsoft Excel are notorious for mangling UTF-8 characters in CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the encoding of the file to UTF-8

This is the sf documentation on how to do it https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324657&type=1&mode=1

There is some good troubleshooting steps in the documentation above that have worked well in the past.

> 1. Find the file.
> 2. Right click the file | select Open With | Notepad.
> 3. Select File | Save As.
> 4. Navigate to the folder where you want to save your file.
> 5. Enter a name for your file and append .csv to the end of the file name.
> 6. Select UTF-8 encoding.
> 7. Click Save.
> 8. Open the newly created file in Excel to view your data.